# why won't children of the body element take percentage heights?

Tags: html, css

having given the `html` and `body` elements a  `height: 100%` height,

and also having given a child element of body, say, `main` a `height: 100%` height,

it refuses to take the height.

but if a child element of `main` is given a `height: 50%` height, it will work given `main` has a set height.

Why does this work for here and not for the latter?

Edit*

here's a working code

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Height</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main> </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: share a working example

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: for height in % the parent element needs a defined height. By default the height of an element is calculated to fit content. As such the child elements dont know what a height in % means.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  added

Comment: and what's the issue? your code works fine

Comment: @tacoshy I understand that. The body element receives it's height from the html element and it from the veiwport. which is why I'm confused the main element isn't taking height from the body despite it having height. (this also wont work if the body element is given any fixed/ vh height)

Comment: @Estif: when you click the "run snippet" button in your post you can see it works as expected, `main` gets stretched to the full height of the viewport. (plus the body padding which you forgot to remove and which due to a box sizing default of `content-box` _adds_ to the 100%) So, what is the issue exactly? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I seems you are correct. The only explanation is React does something to prevent main from taking the height.

Comment: @CherryDT y'all are right. it works for pure html + css. So like I said, must be React doing something...

Comment: I guess it adds an element that is not on 100% height between the body and the main tag